# Why are the comment on my page getting out of order and not showing up at times?

Tags: comments, facebook-page

I run a page and when I post something once I get up to so many comments the comments start to get out of order and also will not show up when I go to check them. This issue has been going on for almost two months.

Comment: http://facebook.com/help

Answer (score 2):

Facebook told Mashable that this is an experiment. They are randomizing the order of comments in page threads to see if it increases engagement. For reasons I won't go into here having to do with the way animal rescue works, hundreds of animals have died already and are dying every day as a direct result of this experiment.

Facebook does not provide customer or tech support. They are conducting this experiment on only some pages. If you have it happening on yours, too bad. Facebook will neither address the issue or allow you to opt out of the experiment.

Facebook has utter disdain for its users. The only solution is to migrate your fan base to another platform. I've already posted and begun the process of letting my fans know that that is in the works.

If you feel it is more important to survive on facebook in spite of this kind of treatment, well, you've been warned. They think your are dirt, and that's why they treat you like this.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question - which in and of itself is poorly composed - and is more of a rant about how evil Facebook is vs. discussing the question asked.